# check file permissions on remote user with credentials using java

Tags: java, file, network-programming

I wanted to check if the given file path(can be shared path,local path on remote windows server) on remote windows machine is existing,is directory and has write permissions from windows machine.

I will be supplied with remote host name, userid,password and file path.

I am using java 1.6

for example:

from my windows machine, I need to access `\\ABDCDMACHINE\DDRIVE\FFOLDER\XXFILE`

I know this can be done using File API. methods in this API, takes parameter of URI/URL, but I want to know how form URL with user name and password included in it.

Comment: Please show a little bit of effort. Writing "urgent" is not going to convince anyone to help you. What have you done so far?

Comment: This might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011264/how-to-read-a-file-from-remote-system-using-java

Comment: I have done for local path

Comment: I meant code. Show us what you've tried so far on your own.

Comment: @Vivek, the link does not show any example of passing credentials and accessing the file path.

Comment: @Vivin, If I know which class to use to access the remote path ,then I would have not asked any question mostly.

Comment: Did you try googling? The first thing that pops up is the `File` API. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html); there is a link to the older File I/O API from Java 6 as well.

Comment: @Vivin, I looked at this API, I could not find way to pass the credentails to the reomote server, if you know you may help , as I don't have much time to read complete documentation.

Comment: This is what I got after googling for "java file i/o remote windows share credentials"; it's even on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599999/write-i-o-file-to-shared-network-drive-using-credentials).

Comment: thanks Vivin. I got the below.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724576/read-remote-file-in-java-which-needs-username-and-password

Comment: If you have found a solution for your question, please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @vivin, I have a question, can we use this third party libraries in the  real time development. because I am working for a client

Comment: @Kelly S. French, SO will not allow me to accept answer less than 2 days old

Comment: No worries, it will have to wait for two days before marking as accepted. In the meantime keep an eye out for other answers that may be better solutions.

Comment: @mahesh I would imagine you could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using

either http://jcifs.samba.org/

OR VFS

[Read remote file in java which needs username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724576/read-remote-file-in-java-which-needs-username-and-password)

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. Doesn't address the problem of how to check the file permissions

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Java [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class.