# Java network path not found error

Tags: java, networking

I have this code. I am running code on one of the machines in LAN and trying to write a file on other machine in the same LAN. Can I do this by following way? I am getting exception:FileNotFound 
package jcsp1;

```
import java.io.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\cmds.txt"));
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("\\\\192.168.1.223\\D:\\test.txt"));

            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011264/how-to-read-a-file-from-remote-system-using-java

Comment: What is the network share name on `192.168.1.223` to which you are trying to copy the file?  Try using Windows Explorer and put in `\\192.168.1.223` to browse to the computer and see if it's accessible and what shares it might have available

Comment: If the D drive on the remote machine does not have its own share you might want to try `\\192.168.1.223\d$`, this share is available for all drives (if your user has the permission to contact the remote machine)