# File.exists() doesnt work on Linux SUSE

Tags: java, filesystems, remote-access

Below code works if I run it on Windows OS but fails on Linux SUSE

```
File sourceDir = new File("//10.152.165.89/sampleFolder/files");
if(sourceDir.exists() {
    Files [] dirFiles = sourceDir.listFiles();
}
```

I shared a directory files on machine *`10.152.165.89`* which is running on Windows 7 and the above code is running on Linux SUSE.

Can anyone please suggest the proper way to create an instance of File and access files inside 'files' directory?

Comment: Maybe your Linux machine can't access 10.152.165.89?

Comment: That looks like an SMB path. Are you sure Linux supports it?

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011264/how-to-read-a-file-from-remote-system-using-java

Comment: What is SMB path by the way?

Comment: Thanks Mateo for the Link. The above code is executed in a JSP deployed on Tomcat in Linux, and the Linux machine is having access to the "//10.152.165.89/sampleFolder/files" directory of windows.

Comment: @SriVikasRam //10.152.165.89/sampleFolder/files is a windows specific way to refer to a file over a network on another server. Windows will access that remote server using the SMB protocol. This is windows specific, linux does not support this way of referring to a file name on a remote server.

Comment: Thanks nos... Can you please suggest a way to access that directory ? Any api that works on both Linux and Windows ?

Comment: I have addressed above problem using RMI..